# BETWEEN com inner join não funciona

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com um problema ao fazer uma consulta usando o between com inner join, a consulta simplesmente não está funcionando, ela retorna os resultados como se o between não estivesse na consulta. O que estou fazendo errado?

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN matriculas ON (matriculas.idaluno = usuarios.id) WHERE matriculas.idcurso = :idcurso AND matriculas.data BETWEEN :dataini AND :datafim ORDER BY usuarios.nome ASC LIMIT 0,20
```

Estou colocando tudo certinho, inclusive as datas estou colocando no padrão americano Y-m-d que é o que o operador between aceita. Sem usar inner join, a consulta funciona bem.

Vale lembrar que estou usando pdo.

Answer (score -1):

Tente fazer com esta `query`:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
INNER JOIN matriculas ON matriculas.idaluno = usuarios.id AND matriculas.data BETWEEN :dataini AND :datafim
WHERE matriculas.idcurso = :idcurso
ORDER BY usuarios.nome ASC
LIMIT 0,20
```

Comment: Essa consulta está mais errada do que a minha kkkk

Comment: Operador between tem que ser depois do where, não faz sentido o jeito que você colocou

Comment: @LeandroSilvaCampos você esta enganado, o operador `BETWEEN` não precisa estar após o `WHERE`. Faça o seguinte, coloque a estrutura e os dados dessas duas tabelas no SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: olha vlw por tentar ajudar mas definitivamente esse não era o problema, pois testei do jeito que você falou e não retornou nenhum resultado dessa forma. Mas já consegui arrumar, meu problema era nos valores que da consulta